# How to show data from several HTTP-pages with one StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter

I am using HTTP-Parse to get data from Internet.
and i need to show data in one Row Widget from two different HTTP-page(ex one is from A-site and the other is B-site in Row Widget).

now i am using `FutureBuilder`widget and in that Widget i add the other `FutureBuilder`. but i think it's not good.is there any other ways?

i am using like this

```dart
FutureBuilder{
future: Afunc(),
builder:(context, snapshot){
     if(snapshot.hasdata){
       return FutureBuilder(
              future:Bfunc(),
          builder:(context, snapshot)     {
      ~~~~~~~
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if you use `StatefulWidget` then you dont need any `FutureBuilder`s - simply use `setState` when your remote data is received

Comment: oh thank you i will do that and can i ask one more thing? if data is big and i want run background how can i do?

Comment: big data? so you want to parse that big data in the background?

Comment: I mean now it's not necessary but later i need so ... yes and big data means a mount of data  if i use setstate i think there's long loading so i asked what if the data is so big or huge

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing

Comment: thank you i didn't think about that even if i knew about that

Comment: i have no idea what you mean by that

Comment: i mean i knew compute method but i didn't think